# How to add a full name on psql database using html select method and php?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

**My goal is to get the names on one of my tables on my psql database and add them to other table using the HTML form select method. I am able to get the names but unfortunately It´s adding only the first names. And I also want to add the number of each name but for all the names it´s only add the number of the last name.**

*Any help?*

**my code**

```
<select style="width: 300px" type=text name=diurno value="<?php echo $nome; ?>"><br>
<?php
$sql = "select * from professore1 where coordenacao='$coordenacao' order by coordenacao;";
$res = pg_query ($con, $sql);
for ($i= 0; $i < pg_numrows($res);$i++) {
  $nome = pg_fetch_result ($res, $i, "nome");
  $numero = pg_fetch_result ($res, $i, "numero");
  echo "<option value = $nome>$nome";
}
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $numero;?>" name="numero" required>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $numero;?>" name="numero" required>
```

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSbwJ.png)

Comment: please show the fields in the table, and tell us which ones you want to use. We can't guess your field names!

Comment: Also this: `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $numero;?>" name="numero" required>` makes no sense. If you want to send the number in your form, it should be included as the "value" of the option e.g. `echo "<option value = '$numero'>$nome</option>";`

Comment: thanks for your help @ADyson I added the image of the table. God bless

Comment: ok well now I showed you how to make the `<option` correctly (with the closing `</option>` part as well, notice! ) please try it again, I think it would print all the names and numbers successfully.

Comment: Thanks again @ADyson. I have done this ways echo "<option value = '$numero'>$nome</option>";. But now is only adding the number but not the names. My idea is to add both the full name and the number.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the names? Just add the number as a foreign key. If you need to get the name later you can do a Join query between the two tables. That's how relational databases are supposed to be used.

Comment: That's a good idea but I don't have any knowledge about join tables . I'll search about join tables I'll get back to you if I found any difficulty. Thanks a lot